# Print PDF from Excel 2003 without having to download addon?

Tags: excel, pdf-generation, vba

I am currently running Excel 2013.  I have a userform where data is feeding into an excel sheet behind it.  The userform has been coded so that the user does not have direct access to the sheets behind it.  Instead, buttons have been added that run macros to print off individual worksheets in PDF format.  This works great in cases where a user is running Excel 2007 or better.  Below is a small chunk of how I'm currently accomplishing my task.

```
Private Print_Confirm As Boolean
Private ThisFile As String
Private dt As String
Public oSHELL As Object, sDesktopPath As String

If Application.Version >= 12# Then
    Sheets("Home").Select
    ThisFile = Range("A21").Value
    dt = Format(CStr(Now), "yyyy_mm-dd_hhmm")
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    sDesktopPath & "\" & ThisFile & "_" & dt & ".pdf", Quality:= _
    xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=True
Else
' Sub routine here to handle 2003?
End If
```

So to restate my question - **Is it possible to print a sheet as a PDF from 2003 without having to download an add on/converter**

Comment: Not that I am aware of. You need an Excel Add-On or 3rd party applications like Adobe, Primopdf etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, office/windows only comes with a  XPS printer which at least is comparable to the printing of PDF. Have you considered using XPS?

If XPS  is no solution, you have bad luck because without addon etc. Office does not support  PDF.
Maybe you can install a PDF Printer which indeed is no addon or a converter. It's a  printer interface  that prints onto a PDF via software instead of printing on paper via printer.